# C language pointers and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[]="PRODUCTION 2019";
    char *p=c;
    printf("%s",p+p[3]-p[5]);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how the output is **RODUCTION 2019** . Can someone explain me in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p[3]` and `p[5]` are the letters `D` and `C` respectively. Even without knowing their actual ASCII code, the difference of those codes is `1`, and thus the result is

```
printf("%s",p+1);
```

Edit: the codes are 67 and 68, so it is `p+68-67` in detailed form.

Answer (score 1):

Because `p[3]` is `'D'` and `p[5]` is `'C'` then `p[3]-p[5]` is  `1` and the whole expression `p+p[3]-p[5]` is just `p + 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s",p+p[3]-p[5] );
```

This is proceeded as follows

p+'D'-'C'
= p+1

And if p points at starting of string i.e. at P,
pointer p+1 points at 'R' and that's why string starting from R is printed.

Answer (score 0):

p[3] is the 4th element in the array and p[5] is the sixth.

In this case, the 4th and 6th elements are D and C respectively and their difference: 'D' - 'C' is equal to 1.

As a result, your printf statement is equivalent to:

```
printf("%s", p + 1);
```

which prints the string beginning from the second character.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
printf("%s",p+p[3]-p[5]);
```

you are playing with fire. It's just for luck that your code doesn't crash.

Let's try to list some facts:

1. Format `%s` is for printing strings. A string (char *) is expected for this format.
2. `printf("%s",p);` would correctly print `"PRODUCTION 2019"`. because `p` is a char * variable pointing to the complete string.
3. `p[3]` and `p[5]` are **NOT** strings. They are chars; more precisely the fourth and the fifth chars of `"PRODUCTION 2019"`: 'D' and 'C' respectively. But they are also byte integers, which value is 0x44 and 0x43 respectively.
4. `p+p[3]-p[5]` is actually a string: it's `p` with some offset. What offset? 0x44 ('D') - 0x43 ('C') = 1.

For these reasons your printf is equivalent to

```
printf("%s",p+1);
```

so it is correct if it prints the string pointed by p starting from the second character (p[1] or *p+1*).

But it is actually playing with fire! What if `p[n]-p[m]` would result in a negative offset? It would result in an attempt to print characters prior to the beginning of p, so in undefined behaviour. The same would happen if `p[n]-p[m]` (e.g. 'Z'-'A') is so big to end up beyond the given string lenght.